# Woocommerce Custom Field on Custom Order Details Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Looking over the docs, there does not appear to be a clear way to display a custom field on the customer's order details page. I have no problem getting my custom fields to display on the admin order details or the customer's email.

The only way I can see that it can be done is if by copying over the "woocommerce/order/order-details.php" in the theme's folder. This is undesirable as it requires me to have a lingering template file that may or may not need to be updated if woo developers change the original.

Is there a filter that can allow me to add the custom field to the customer's order details page without relying on a template?

Just to clarify, the page I am looking to add this is when the user completes the order (their receipt page).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Resolved. I missed this function in the docs.... "woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table".

This function will add your custom fields to the order details page. In my case...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'nolo_custom_field_display_cust_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function nolo_custom_field_display_cust_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Pickup Location').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Pickup Location', true ). '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Pickup Date').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Pickup Date', true ). '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you post an example, need to add sku there. Thanks!

Comment: Updated with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I am using woocommerce-gravityforms-product-addons,  woocommerce, gravity-forms-placeholder-support-add-on and gravityforms. problem is that my custom fields show me in chakout page but not showing in order ![enter image description here][1]in backend.