# Display Custom Field in Wordpress / Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, field

I added some custom fields to the checkout page in Woocommerce, and I would like the data from the custom fields to show on the following receipt page (Order Details) after checkout is completed.

Everything else is working fine, it posts the custom data to my admin section, etc. I just can't figure out why it won't display on the order details page.

I came across the following post, but it didn't work for me either.

[Woocommerce Custom Field on Custom Order Details Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563693/woocommerce-custom-field-on-custom-order-details-page)

Below is the code I'm using to try and display the data.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_receipt', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_receipt($order){
echo 'Cardholder Name: ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'cc_name', true ) . '<br>';
echo 'Card Number: ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'cc_number', true ) . '<br>';
echo 'Expiration Date: ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'cc_exp', true ) . '<br>';
echo 'CVV Code: ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'cc_cvv', true ) . '<br>';
echo 'Billing Zip: ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'cc_zip', true ) . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the meta is `cc_name` and not `_cc_name`? What if you `var_dump(get_post_custom($order->id));` to see all the custom meta fields?

Comment: I don't really understand the var_dump ... when I do that I get this. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Cardholder's Name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "John Doe" } ["2. Card Number"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "1254-1010-1010-5455" } ["3. Expiration Date"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "11/18" } ["4. CVV Code"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "123" } ["5. Billing Zip"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "75150" }

Comment: I fixed it. Stupid mistake of course...my variables didn't match. In one section I had '1. Cardholders Name' and then in another 'Cardholders Name' without the 1.

Comment: The `var_dump()` was just to show you what keys had actually been saved so that you could compare them to what you were trying to retrieve. As you found out your meta keys didn't match.